# Keeping a running tally of clicks in a .json file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to create a real-time polling / quizzing app for my course website.  This is what I have in mind: For each quiz, I will have a correspoding `.json` file which will keep a list of the questions and corresponding options, as well as a tally of the number of users who have chosen each option.

I would like to have that upon a user's selection and submission of an answer, the tally corresponding to that question/answer is incremented by one.  Any help would be appreciated.

#### `html`

(the site is built with `Hugo`, hence the `{{ ... }}` syntax)

```html
...
{{ range .Site.Data.quiz.questions }}
<section>
    {{ $name := .question }}
    {{ $name }}
    {{ range .options }}
        <label class="container">{{ .name }}
            <input type="radio" name="{{ $name }}">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    {{ end }}
</section>
{{ end }}
```

#### `quiz.json`

```json
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "question": "What do you think about astrology?",
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "It's nonsense.",
          "tally": 0,
          "correct": true
        },
        {
          "name": "It's legit!",
          "tally": 0,
          "correct": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you maintain a DB instead of a json file?

Comment: @varunagarwal does DB stand for "database"?  I'm a newbie, but I'm trying

Comment: Yup, DB means database.

Comment: Yes, maintaining a database is a lot easier. You can take your pick from a variety of them. And then you could just run a query to update the `tally` field of any question.